# Share button on Xamarin.forms.ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, share-button

I'm a beginner on Xamarin ant try to create simple app with Xamarin.forms.
Now i need to add share button (square + arrow like on Safari on iPhone) to my App. As I know that Android and IOS are differant so that I use DependencyService. 
It works good on Android using Intent but can't do it on IOS.
can you help me please.
thanks all,
**this is my code**

**PCL**

```
    var x = DependencyService.Get<IShareable>(); 
    x.ShareText("any text to share");
```

**Android**

```
public void ShareText(string textToShear) 
{
  var myIntent = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);      
  myIntent.SetType("text/plain"); 
  myIntent.PutExtra("sms_body", textToShear); 
  Forms.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(myIntent,"Choose an App"));
}
```

**IOS**

```
public void ShareText(string textToShear) 
{
 //what i should do 
}
```

Comment: Please post your work.

Comment: sorry i can't set the code format

Comment: Edit your original question to add the code rather than trying to put it in a comment (and maybe even delete the comments)

Comment: Press ctrl+k to enter code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [UIActivityViewController](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AMonoTouch.UIKit.UIActivityViewController).

It will look something like this:

```
public void ShareText(string textToShare) 
{
    var activityController = new UIActivityViewController(new NSObject[] { UIActivity.FromObject(textToShare) }, null);
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(activityController, true, null);
}
```

Comment: @Kastour, how did you do it ? i have tried it, but it is doing nothing on button touch : /

Answer (score 1):

I am in the exact same position.

What I have found out so far:

- iOS apps typically use something called Sharekit, but I haven't found anyone using that with Xamarin.Forms
- Since iOS 6 there is an easier way to share with objective c, but I'm not sure how we could convert that to C# / Xamarin.
- There is a social plugin for Xamarin called Xamarin.Social that allows users to log in and post things from your app.  Of course this isn't what we want to do... ideally we would like the same functionality that is in Android.

I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help.  If I find an answer that works I will update you.